# Layout: Prevent view from cropping to fill screen - CameraView

Tags: android, layout, camera

I am experimenting with the [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat) android camera library. Right now the camera preview is cropping itself to fill the screen (16:9) rather than showing the full sensor preview (4:3). I am trying to figure out how to show the full preview so what you see matches the image that is taken.

I expected the following to do that (maintain the standard 4:3 ratio in the camera preview rather than filling and cropping):

```
<!--NOTE THIS IS FOR PORTRAIT VIEW-->
<io.fotoapparat.view.CameraView
android:id="@+id/camera_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

But it still fills the width and height. If I give absolute sizes for the layout width and height in 4:3 it does in fact display the full sensor but obviously absolute sizes are not reasonable to use for this.

```
<io.fotoapparat.view.CameraView
android:id="@+id/camera_view"
android:layout_width="1440px"
android:layout_height="1920px"/>
```

Is there something I am overlooking? I am not great with layouts yet.